# Did I solve exercise 4.5.4 (b) of 'How to Prove it' by velleman correctly and concisely?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

> 4.5.4 Suppose R is a strict partial order on A. Let S be the reflexive closure of R.
>
> (b) Show that if R is a strict total order, then S is a total order.

Suppose R is a strict total order. Then, R is transitive and irreflexive.

Let S be the reflexive closure of R. Let T be R ∪ Ia. Let U be a relation on A. Suppose R ⊆ U and U is reflexive.

Let x ∈ T. Since T=R ∪ Ia, x ∈ R or x ∈ Ia. If x ∈ R, then x ⊆ U. If x ∈ Ia, then since U is reflexive, x ∈ U.

Thus, T ⊆ U. Since U was arbitrary, R ⊆ T, and T is reflexive, T is the reflexive closure of R.

It follows that S=T=R ∪ Ia. Let (a, b) ∈ S and (b, c) ∈ S. Then, (a, b) ∈ R ∪ Ia and (b, c) ∈ R ∪ Ia.

If (a, b) ∈ R and (b, c) ∈ R, then since R is transitive, (a, c) ∈ R.

If (a, b) ∈ R and (b, c) ∈ Ia, then since b=c, (a, c) ∈ R.

If (a, b) ∈ Ia and (b, c) ∈ R, then since a=b, (a, c) ∈ R.

If (a, b) ∈ Ia and (b, c) ∈ Ia, then since a=b=c, (a, c) ∈ Ia.

Since a, b, and c were arbitrary, S is transitive.

Let (x, y) ∈ R and (y, x) ∈ R. Since R is transitive, (x, x) ∈ R.

Since, R is irreflexive, this leads to a contradiction. Hence, R is asymmetric.

Now, suppose (d, e) ∈ S and (e, d) ∈ S. Then, (d, e) ∈ R ∪ Ia and (e, d) ∈ R ∪ Ia.

Since R is asymmetric, (d, e) ∈ R ∧ (e, d) ∈ R is false.

Since R is irreflexive, (d, e) ∈ R ∧ (e, d) ∈ Ia and (d, e) ∈ Ia ∧ (e, d) ∈ R are both false.

However, (d, e) ∈ Ia and (e, d) ∈ Ia is true. Thus, if (d, e) ∈ S and (e, d) ∈ S, then d=e.

Therefore, S is antisymmetric.

Since R is a strict total order, ∀x ∈ A∀y ∈ A(xRy ∨ yRx ∨ x = y). Let x and y be arbitrary elements in A.

Since S = R ∪ Ia, (x, y) ∈ S or (y, x) ∈ S if y ≠ x. If x=y, since S is reflexive, (x, y) ∈ S and (y, x) ∈ S.

Since x and y were arbitrary, ∀x ∈ A∀y ∈ A(xSy ∨ ySx).

Since S is reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric, and ∀x ∈ A∀y ∈ A(xSy ∨ ySx),
S is a total order.

---

While I think the proof is probably correct, it seems verbose.

Can anyone help make it more concise?

Comment: Please consider using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) for typesetting mathematics. Right now the question looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/nM2VeAj.png) in my browser, which is quite awkward as I'd need to scroll left and right constantly to be able to read anything.

Comment: I removed scroll bars. How do you like it now?

Comment: Where has this book been all my mathematics career...

Comment: I also own this book too, but I haven't reached farther into this chapter. I'm only on the easy chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that $S$ is a total order, we need to show antisymmetry, transitivity and totality.

**Lemma:** Take $a,b \in A$. Then $aSb$ and (not $aRb$) implies that $a = b$. This is because the reflexive closure only adds pairs of the form $(x,x)$ to the relation. In fact, $S \setminus R = \{(x,x) | x \in A\}$.

**Antisymmetry**

Suppose there exist $a \neq b \in A$ such that $aSb$ and $bSa$. As $a \neq b$, we know only one of $aRb$ or $bRa$ is true. As the other is false, and we have both $aSb$ and $bSa$, the lemma imples $a = b$, a contradiction. Therefore, $a=b$.

**Transitivity**
Take $a,b,c \in A$ such that $aSb, bSc$. There are four cases:

1. $aRb, bRc$. $R$ is transitive, so it follows that $aRc$ and thus $aSc$.
2. $aSb, bRc$ and (not $aRb$). By lemma, $a = b$, and we substitute $aRc$ and so $aSc$.
3. $aRb, bSc$ and (not $bRc$). As above, $b = c$, and we substitute $aRc$ implying $aSc$.
4. $aSb, bSc$ and (not $aRb$),(not $bRc$). From the lemma, $a=b=c$. $S$ is reflexive, so $aSc$.

**Totality**

Take $a = b \in A$. Because $S$ is a reflexive closure, we know that $aSb$. Now suppose that $a \neq b \in A$. Then we have $(a,b) \in R$, and therefore $(a,b) \in S$.

---

Your proof is probably similar to this, but it's difficult to read. I think the formatting is more important than the verbosity. Brief cases look better as a list, and you don't need to put each sentence on a new line.

Comment: Thanks. You're a great teacher. By the way, there is a typo.
exit -> exist

Comment: Any time! Also, if you don't know latex, that's a really good place to start. It's pretty simple to pick up the basics as you go along, and any graders you have in the future will be thrilled to bits to receive neatly typed homework.